# How would you show that a function is continuous in every $x_{0}$?

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, derivatives, continuity

I could only show that a function is continuous if a $x_{0}$ was given, let's say given function is $f(x)=x^{2}$ and I need to show continuity at $x_{0}=0$.

I could do that but what if someone told me to show it for all $x_{0}$?

Is a task like that possible at all?

Same question I could ask for differentiability, what if someone told me for all $x_{0}$ or not give me any $x_{0}$?

I have been asking this myself for a long time now and I'd really like to have an answer to that question and appreciate your help very much.

Comment: Let $x_0$ denote an *arbitrary* element of $\mathbb R$ and prove that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$. If that's done then you are ready. Same for differentiation.

Comment: drhab is that correct?

Ok let's say task is: Show that $f(x)=x^{2}$ is continuous in every $x_{0}$.
Then I do: $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}^{-}}(x^{2})=x^{2}$ and
$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}^{+}}(x^{2})=x^{2}$ both same thus function is continuous in every $x_{0}$?

Comment: Almost. the RHS of the equalities in your comment must be $x_0^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You show it (in symbols) for an arbitrary $x_0$, then you note that since $x_0$ was arbitrary, it holds everywhere. That's the basic procedure to show something holds everywhere.

Comment: Ok let's say task is: Show that $f(x)=x^{2}$ is continuous in every $x_{0}$.
Then I do: $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}^{-}}(x^{2})=x^{2}$ and
$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}^{+}}(x^{2})=x^{2}$ both same thus function is continuous in every $x_{0}$?

Comment: Yes, except the limit is equal to $x_0^2$.

Comment: Ok thank you, very easy then.

Answer (score 1):

We need to prove that for every $\varepsilon >0$ exists $\delta>0$ so that implication holds for every $x$: $|x-0|<\delta \implies |x^2-0|<\varepsilon$. This really holds for $\delta=\sqrt{\varepsilon}$, so function is continuous at $x=0$.